Resources to develop the statistical models for a sports betting website
Please help me with resources to develop a sports betting website. Just so you know, I am a complete novice.
I am specifically looking for algorithms to calculate the odds, decide how much to charge bettors, pay them after wins/losses, extract the maximum profit for the betting company, etc. I need help developing the (statistical) models rather than setting up the website itself.
I would appreciate your help with books, papers and/or GitHub or other open-source codes.
